# how to get city and state name from location

Tags: facebook-graph-api, location

We get user\friends location as follows -->

```
location =  {id = 104048449631599; name = "Menlo Park, California";};
```

On our side, location is split into city and state. In our database we store the city and state is 2 different columns or tables. We are building app for US market only. Would it be safe to assume the location name has only 2 components - city, state name.  Use "," as delimiter. As per my understanding the Id is unique, is their FB service which if provide id will give city and state information separately.

Comment: Any news on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the scopes correct in the request, like below

```
location{location{city,state,country,latitude,longitude,region_id}}
```

Reference:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/location/

This is the documentation for the location

**Get User Location Information
Requirements
The user_location permission is required.**

```
Sample Request
curl -i -X GET \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/{graph-api-version}/{user-id}?    
    fields=location{location{city,state,region_id}}&access_token={user-access-token}"

Sample Response
{
  "location": {
    "location": {
      "city": "San Jose",
      "state": "CA",
      "region_id": 3847
    },
    "id": "111948542155151"   //location-id
  },
  "id": "{user-id}"
}
```

PHP-based code is as below,

```
// get profile info
                $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=email,birthday,location{location{city,state,country,latitude,longitude,region_id}},gender');//public_profile,email,user_birthday,user_location,user_gender
                $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
                $email = $userNode->getField('email');
                $birthdayNode = $userNode->getField('birthday');
                $birthday = $birthdayNode->format('Y-m-d');
                $locationNode = $userNode->getField('location');
                $location = $locationNode->getField('location');
                $city = $location->getField('city');
                $state = $location->getField('state');
                $country = $location->getField('country');
                $latitude = $location->getField('latitude');
                $longitude = $location->getField('longitude');
```